# Trimming asterisks from the start of docstring lines

Tags: php, regex

I want to remove comments from a docstring:

```
/**
 * 
 * Another method
 *
 * * This is a bullet point
 *
 * @return [type] [description]
 */
```

Into:

```
Another method

* This is a bullet point

@return [type] [description]
```

What I have so far:

```
<?php
$string = substr($docstring, 3, -2); // Strips opening/closing tags
$string = preg_replace('/^\s*\*\s*/m', '', $string);
```

Unforunately, the regex doesn't work very well and  gives me this:

```
* Another method
@return [type] [description]
```

It seems the regex is matching more than one line and then skips to the next start of line missing the first one with actual content.

The following variation seemed promising but it doesn't work either:

```
/^\s*\*\s*?(?=>\S|$)/m
```

**Edit:** To clarify, I want to trim only one asterisk from the start of the line

Comment: Find: `/\*\*.*?\*/` , replace with empty string, does this work for you?

Comment: I'd use http://ideone.com/nqyv03. 1) Match all the multiline comments, 2) trim from the asterisks and whitespace at the beginning of each line.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In my question I mentioned that `/^\s*\*\s*?(?=>\S|$)/m` held promise.

It turns out that pcre just doesn't like multiline mode with lookaheads. So to get the same effect, I got rid of the lookahead and made it a capture and replace:

```
<?php
$string = substr($docstring, 3, -2); // Strips opening/closing tags
$string = preg_replace('/^\s*\*\s*?(\S|$)/m', '\1', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should suffice:

```
$docstring = '/**
 * 
 * Another method
 * @return [type] [description]
*/';

$result = preg_replace('~^[\s*/]+~m', '', $docstring);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see what's wrong in your code and duplicated your result. But the following code seems working.

```
$string = preg_replace('/^[\s\*]+/m', '', $string);
```

Comment: This will trim multiple asterisks from the start of the line, I only want it to trim one (And the surrounding whitespace)

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Why use the lookahead if you can leave it out?

```
preg_replace('/^\W?\*?+\W?/m', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to parse the code snippet to extract multi-line comments using [`token_get_all()`](http://php.net/token_get_all) :

```
function docBlocks($code)
{
    return array_filter(token_get_all($code), function($token) {
            if ($token[0] == T_DOC_COMMENT) {
                if (preg_match('~^\s*/\*\*~', $token[1])) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Then apply substituting asterisks and removing commenting delimiters:

```
var_dump(preg_replace(['~/\*\*~',
    '~\s*\*/~',
    '~^ *\*~m'],
    '',
    array_column(docBlocks($snippet), 1))
);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(82) "

 Another method

 * This is a bullet point

 @return [type] [description]"
  [1]=>
  string(82) "

 Another method

 * This is a bullet point

 @return [type] [description]"
}
```

**[PHP live demo](http://ideone.com/iln5xx)**

Answer (score 0):

I see what's going on here and can explain why you got what you got.

The following is the content of $string:

```
 *
 * Another method
 * @return [type] [description]
```

Then the regex '/^\s*\*\s*/m' will match everything before the second * because \s will also match the newline. Then the first two lines would be considered/treated as just one line and the second * will be left unremoved.